# Does Allah punish people on this earth?

Tags: punishment

I heard from Nouman Ali Khan that Allah only punishes the people in the world when there is a prophet with them and they abandon the prophet. I am not clear about Allah punishing people in this world, so are earthquakes, tsunamis etc punishment or just trials ?

Answer (score -1):

And Lut said:

> No one before you has gone as crazy as you are. You leave your women and go to the men.

And according to this story, Quran states:

> We rained fireballs onto their heads
>   And according to another verse from Quran:
>   We sent strong winds to the sinful Hud generation

And Quran tells:

> We punish them in this world and in apocalypses.

Comment: Please share the verse numbers too when quoting the Quran. It makes reference easier.

Comment: I understand Allah punished people in the past but I am talking about now. Does Allah punish people on the earth after Prophet Muhammad P.B.U.H has gone?